# How generate primary key with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How to bake model without PK?

While execute bake command, received error: "Cannot generate views for models with no primary key".

Comment: Can i generate tables wihout PK with bake? Maybe a configuration to ignore the PK rules.

Answer (score 1):

> Phinx automatically creates an auto-incrementing primary key column called id for every table.

The id option sets the name of the automatically created identity field, while the primary_key option selects the field or fields used for primary key. id will always override the primary_key option unless it’s set to false. If you don’t need a primary key set id to false without specifying a primary_key, and no primary key will be created

To specify an alternate primary key, you can specify the primary_key option when accessing the Table object. Let’s disable the automatic id column and create a primary key using two columns instead:

**Read:** https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/phinx/migrations.html#creating-a-table

```
 /**
 * Migrate Up.
 */
public function up()
{
    $table = $this->table('followers', ['id' => false]);
    $table->addColumn('user_id', 'integer')
          ->addColumn('follower_id', 'integer')
          ->addColumn('created', 'datetime')
          ->save();
}
```

Comment: Alright. But i belivie this is not my case. All of my tables are in database and i use the command: bin/cake bake all Table_name for generate the mvc of the table. But a lot of the tables dont have a PK. Understand? Im new in cakephp(sorry, if i say something wrong).

Comment: I have add answer at your question: " generate primary key with cakephp" && "Can i generate tables wihout PK with bake?"  You need to ask how to bake model without PK.